# Как сделать чтобы пользователь мог менять локализацию внутри приложения? Почему у меня не срабатывает код?

Tags: java, android, locale, configuration

Вот код, Toast message возникает, но язык надписей не меняется.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Locale locale1;
    Locale locale2;
    Configuration configuration1;
    Configuration configuration2;

    TextView hello;
    TextView eatMusli;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hello = findViewById(R.id.hello);
        eatMusli = findViewById(R.id.eat_musli);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.ru:
                locale1 = new Locale("ru");
                Locale.setDefault(locale1);
                configuration1 = new Configuration();
                configuration1.locale = locale1;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration1,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Locale in Russia!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;
            case R.id.en:
                locale2 = new Locale("en");
                Locale.setDefault(locale2);
                configuration2 = new Configuration();
                configuration2.locale = locale2;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration2,
                        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Locale in England!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Так выглядят строки:
в ru/string.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="eat_musli">А давай жрать мюсли?</string>
    <string name="hello">Привет!</string>
    <string name="language">Язык</string>
    <string name="ru">Русский</string>
    <string name="en">Инглиш</string>
</resources>
```

в en/string.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="eat_musli">Let\'s eat musli?</string>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
    <string name="language">language</string>
    <string name="en">english</string>
    <string name="ru">russian</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить [перезагрузку](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()) активности:

```
recreate()
```

если же вам нужно незаметно перезагрузить активность, можно ознакомится [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52331896/9363441) с вариантами.

Comment: совет из раздела "купить новый телефон чтобы сменить обои"

Comment: Ответ верный. Без перезапуска активити работать не будет. Можно, конечно, без перезагрузки делать, но это очень долго и сложно. Стандартный и простой 
 способ- как раз пересоздавать активити.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я просто подумал, может моих знаний недостаточно и я чего-то не учел, но у ТС перезагрузки не увидел)

Comment: Спасибо, но почемуто это не обновляет язык в ТекстВью, хотя даже если запросить Локаль и вывести в Toast то показывает уже другую локаль, которую выбрал.

Comment: @AlexRodionow, а вы в разметке активности привязали строковые ресурсы для вашего виджета?